# without extends of class activity how to getget email id's from contacts and get phone no from contacts?

Tags: android

hi all how to implement coding for get email id's from contacts and  get phone no from contacts show me the way to overcome from this problem
note: class doesn't have extends Activity and oncreate() method also so kindly help me to go forward

Comment: When you will create object of that class from activity pass this as an parameter to the class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your class doesnot have extends Activity or onCreate() method. So pass the context parameter from the class which extends Activity to this class.

### sudo code

```
Class A extends Activity{

new ClassB(this);
}
```

here Class B does not extends Activity.
But write the following method to gwt contacts and email id in class B

```
public static void getContactNumbers(Context context) {
    String contactNumber = null;
    int contactNumberType = Phone.TYPE_MOBILE;
    String nameOfContact = null;
    ArrayList<ContactNumberBean> phoneContacts = new ArrayList<ContactNumberBean>();
        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
                null, null, null);
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                String id = cur.getString(cur
                        .getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID));
                nameOfContact = cur
                        .getString(cur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                if (Integer
                        .parseInt(cur.getString(cur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                    Cursor phones = cr
                            .query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                    null,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                            + " = ?", new String[] { id },
                                    null);

                    while (phones.moveToNext()) {
                        contactNumber = phones.getString(phones
                                .getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER));
                        contactNumberType = phones.getInt(phones
                                .getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));

                        phoneContacts
                                .add(new ContactNumberBean(nameOfContact,
                                        contactNumber, contactNumberType));
                    }
                    phones.close();
                }

            }
        }// end of contact name cursor
        cur.close();

}

/**
 * 
 * This method is responsible to get native contacts and corresponding email
 * id (ApplicationConstants.emailContacts)
 * 
 * @param context
 */
public static void getContactEmails(Context context) {
    String emailIdOfContact = null;
    int emailType = Email.TYPE_WORK;
    String contactName = null;
    ArrayList<ContactEmailBean> emailContacts = new ArrayList<ContactEmailBean>();



        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
        Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
                null, null, null);
        if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cur.moveToNext()) {
                String id = cur.getString(cur
                        .getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID));
                contactName = cur
                        .getString(cur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
                // Log.i(TAG,"....contact name....." +
                // contactName);

                cr.query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                                + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);

                Cursor emails = cr.query(Email.CONTENT_URI, null,
                        Email.CONTACT_ID + " = " + id, null, null);
                while (emails.moveToNext()) {
                    emailIdOfContact = emails.getString(emails
                            .getColumnIndex(Email.DATA));
                    // Log.i(TAG,"...COntact Name ...."
                    // + contactName + "...contact Number..."
                    // + emailIdOfContact);
                    emailType = emails.getInt(emails
                            .getColumnIndex(Phone.TYPE));
                    emailContacts
                            .add(new ContactEmailBean(contactName,
                                    emailIdOfContact, emailType));

                }
                emails.close();

            }
        }// end of contact name cursor
        cur.close();


}
```

Write two bean class

### EmailBean

```
public class ContactEmailBean {
        String emailType = null;
        String nameOfContact = null;

        String emailIdOfContact = null;

        public ContactEmailBean(String nameOfContact, String emailIdOfContact,
                int emailType) {
            switch (emailType) {
            case Email.TYPE_HOME:
                this.emailType = "HOME";
                // do something with the Home number here...
                break;
            case Email.TYPE_MOBILE:
                this.emailType = "MOBILE";
                // do something with the Mobile number here...
                break;
            case Email.TYPE_WORK:
                this.emailType = "WORK";
                // do something with the Work number here...
                break;

            default:
                this.emailType = "OTHER";
                break;
            }
            this.nameOfContact = nameOfContact;
            this.emailIdOfContact = emailIdOfContact;

        }

        public String getNameOfContact() {
            return this.nameOfContact;
        }

        public String getEmailType() {
            return this.emailType;
        }

        public String getEmailIdOfContact() {
            return this.emailIdOfContact;
        }
    }
```

### ContactNumberBean

```
public class ContactNumberBean {
        String phoneNumberType = null;
        String nameOfContact = null;
        String contactNumber = null;

        public ContactNumberBean(String nameOfContact, String contactNumber,
                int contactNumberType) {
            switch (contactNumberType) {
            case Phone.TYPE_HOME:
                this.phoneNumberType = "HOME";
                // do something with the Home number here...
                break;
            case Phone.TYPE_MOBILE:
                this.phoneNumberType = "MOBILE";
                // do something with the Mobile number here...
                break;
            case Phone.TYPE_WORK:
                this.phoneNumberType = "WORK";
                // do something with the Work number here...
                break;
            case Phone.TYPE_WORK_MOBILE:
                this.phoneNumberType = "WORK";
                break;

            case Phone.TYPE_FAX_HOME:
                this.phoneNumberType = "FAX";
                break;
            default:
                this.phoneNumberType = "OTHER";
                break;
            }
            this.nameOfContact = nameOfContact;
            this.contactNumber = contactNumber;

        }

        public String getNameOfContact() {
            return this.nameOfContact;
        }

        public String getPhoneNumberType() {
            return this.phoneNumberType;
        }

        public String getContactNumber() {
            return this.contactNumber;
        }

}
```

Comment: how to implement  ApplicationConstants.phoneContacts                              .add(new ContactNumberBean(nameOfContact,                                    contactNumber, contactNumberType)) please give me solution to overcome from this problem

Comment: hi deepak i am add the comment please edit your answer/how can implement ApplicationConstants and ContactEmailBean ....this is the problem here...................................................................................
                        ApplicationConstants.emailContacts
                                .add(new ContactEmailBean(contactName,
                                        emailIdOfContact, emailType));

Comment: hi deepak please forward some suggestion i am struck in more days thanks

Comment: Hi Laxman, I have edited my answer. Have a look on that Now it wil work for you. Yesterday I left from office thats why i was unable to give you answer

Comment: hi deepak this two bean class is ok how can retrieve total contacts in classA activity class public class AddressBook extends Activity 
{
   
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        ContactList1.getContactEmails(this);
        ContactList1.getContactNumbers(this);
      }

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this code!

```
btn_existing_contacts.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent_contacts = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
            /*contacts.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            contacts.setData(People.CONTENT_URI);*/
            startActivityForResult(intent_contacts, 0);
            //displayContacts();


        }
     });
```

after returning from contacts screen,

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent data)
{
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
String name,mailid,id;
switch(requestCode)
{
case 0:
{
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK )
    {
        Uri contactdata  = data.getData();

        Cursor cur = managedQuery(contactdata, null, null, null, null);


        if(cur.moveToFirst())
        {
            id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            Cursor emailCur = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",new String[]{id}, null); 
            emailCur.moveToFirst();
            String email = emailCur.getString(emailCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));


            name = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            //mailid = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
            //mailid = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email._ID));
            //Toast.makeText(context_contact, "Name:"+name+"\nmailid:"+email, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent_add_invitees = new Intent(<ClassContext>,<ur classname>.class);
            intent_add_invitees.putExtra("invitee_name", name);
            intent_add_invitees.putExtra("invitee_mailid", email);
            setResult(RESULT_OK, intent_add_invitees);
            finish();

        }
    }

}



}
}
```

The Send_invitations .class is the activity where I am using these contacts